# How do you install Firebug if your computer is isolated from the internet?

Tags: firefox, add-in

I have noticed that Firebug and some other addons I have browsed require that Firefox be installed and running for them to be installed.

That's a little inconvenient, given that my development machine is not connected to the internet.  Is there a way to download and install the addins using a flash drive?

Comment: I can see why this question has gotten few "casual" upvotes ;-)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To manually install a Firefox extension into Firefox, download the add-on to your computer. If the download option isn't available, right click on the extension install link and select "Save Link As..". Be sure not to change the file extension. A Firefox extension will usually be a .XPI file.

Next, go to the Firefox drop down menus at the top of the browser. Select File > Open File then select the addon.xpi file and click on Open. The Software Installation window will appear, click install, restart Firefox.

Comment: This wasn't working for me because it seems to download as "part" files now (not as an xpi). I solved it by downloading it in internet explorer.

Comment: In my case, I am using Portable Firefox (version 38.0.5). You may not be able to find 'open file' button cause it's not shown by default at least in this version, however, you can type in the physical path of the .xpi file into the address box of Firefox, like C:\Users\username\blah\blah\firebug-2.0.11-fx.xpi, and that will work fine.

Answer (score 7):

1. open any indexes of version u want,http://getfirebug.com/releases/firebug/1.6/
2. right click on any of the link and choose "save as"
3. There will be one ".xpi" file which l b downloaded locally to ur computer.
4. Copy tat .xpi file and paste it in ur computer/server where there is no internet connection.
5. In that PC/sever,open firefox-->go to tools -->add ons
6. Drag tat copied .xpi file into add ons window and click on install
7. restart firefox
   ur work is done :)

Answer (score 1):

some different way to solve this by using portable version of firefox, you can pack them with all what you need and save it in your flash drive.

http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable

Much easier than download any extension for each instance and install them.

Comment: Yes, I know, but sometimes this question is actual. I believe that this answer can help for someone.

Answer (score 0):

You could trick the program into thinking that you're connected to the Internet

Comment: I have to download Firebug first, and I have the feeling that it will just install it into Firefox on my internet-enabled computer, and I still won't have a standalone installer.